# What occurs when requestAnimationFrame(callback); changes width of an image? repaint or reflow?

Tags: javascript

I have read some topics about reflow and repait this is what I maneged to understand.

> A repaint occurs when changes are made to an elements skin that
>   changes visibility, but do not affect its layout.
>
> A reflow occurs when changes are made to the elements layout.

Anyway, when

> window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);

updates selected image element changing it's width what occurs repaint or reflow.
In MDN the callback parameter was discriebed as:

> A parameter specifying a function to call when it's time to update your animation for the next repaint.

So what occurs after all, reflow or repaint?

Here is an example of my problem:

```js
var jediImg = document.getElementById('jedi-image');
jediImg.src = 'images/jedi-image.jpg';
jediImg.width = 400;

var times = 20,
  update = -1;

var isJediVisible = true;

function animationFrame() {
  if (isJediVisible) {
    jediImg.width = 0;
  } else {
    jediImg.width = 400;
  }
  isJediVisible = !isJediVisible;

  jediImg.width = (20 - times) * 50;
  times += update;
  if (times === 0) {
    update = 1;
  }
  if (times == 20) {
    update = -1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
}
animationFrame();
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change in `width` will trigger the reflow and paint. See more about triggers [here](http://csstriggers.com/).

Comment: Notice, `width` is now not in this list anymore. [It still was in 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215121556/https://csstriggers.com/).